# Move all files to a new directory excluding that directory

Tags: bash

I have the following:

```
~@matrix:~/btp200/assignments> ls -la
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 3 molszewski1 users 4096 Feb  6 13:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 molszewski1 users 4096 Feb  6 13:14 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 molszewski1 users 5727 Feb  6 13:20 ISBN.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 molszewski1 users  361 Feb  6 13:18 ISBN.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 molszewski1 users 3753 Feb  6 13:17 ISBNPrefix.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 molszewski1 users  422 Feb  6 13:15 ISBNPrefix.h
drwxr-xr-x 2 molszewski1 users 4096 Feb  6 13:20 a1
-rw-r--r-- 1 molszewski1 users    0 Feb  6 13:15 a1.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 molszewski1 users 6271 Feb  6 13:18 prefixRanges.txt
~@matrix:~/btp200/assignments> mv * a1
mv: cannot move `a1' to a subdirectory of itself, `a1/a1'
```

How can I move everything into directory `a1` excluding `a1`?

Comment: Well, you already did move everything into `a1` excluding `a1` itself. For avoiding the error message, see the "may already have an answer here" link up top.

Comment: It would be safer to split the move command into copy & remove. See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1231837/670392

Answer (score 15):

One way to include everything but one item is:

```
mv !(a1) a1
```

This is a feature you need to have enabled first with:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: How do i do this in a shell script? I keep getting  ``syntax error near unexpected token `('``

Comment: @rapidclock did you add `shopt -s extglob` initially - **inside the script** ?

Answer (score 6):

```
mv -f * a1
```

This will force the move to happen despite the argument.  Then do an `ls` after and you will see it worked.

Comment: For me this works even without -f

Comment: Ah, you're right. I didn't even think to check that.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using following command

```
find . -maxdepth 1 | grep -v a1| xargs -i mv {} ./a1
```